# What is adding "X-PHP-Originating-Id" to my email header?

Tags: php, email, email-validation

I have a php script that emails form data to me from a hosted provider domain. I do not have access to the php.ini file.

This script was working fine until about a week ago when emails stopped getting sent - no errors on the script, just the emails didn't leave the email server.

The hosting provider claims that it was because of the attribute: "X-PHP-Originating-Id" on my emails tripping the spam filter.

The attribute does appear in my header:

```
Received: (qmail 12927 invoked by uid 30297); 13 Jun 2013 19:14:34 -0000
Received: from unknown (HELO p3pismtp01-006.prod.phx3.secureserver.net) ([72.167.238.6])
      (envelope-sender <noreply@onlineserver.cc>)
      by p3plsmtp21-05.prod.phx3.secureserver.net (qmail-1.03) with SMTP
      for <admin@foo.com>; 13 Jun 2013 19:14:34 -0000
X-IronPort-Anti-Spam-Result: AsoBANYWulFIp+r1fmdsb2JhbABbw0EWDgEBCQsMCBQog3IzPRKHfAMPsnoNlTSBH4QigQcDiSCCAoo4jgWIU4FR
Received: from p3nlsmtp20.shr.prod.phx3.secureserver.net ([72.167.234.245])
  by p3pismtp01-006.prod.phx3.secureserver.net with ESMTP; 13 Jun 2013 12:14:29 -0700
Received: from P3NW8SHG346.phx3.gdhosting.gdg ([184.168.27.83]) 
  by p3nlsmtp20.shr.prod.phx3.secureserver.net with 
id nvEV1l00V1nbBZC01vEV2b; Thu, 13 Jun 2013 12:14:29 -0700
Date: Thu, 13 Jun 2013 12:14:29 -0700
Subject: Client Assessment Form
To: owner@foo.com, admin@foo.com, admin2@foo.com, owner2@foo.com
X-PHP-Originating-Id: [10541707]
From: chef@foo.com\r\nReply-To: chef@foo.com
X-Mailer: PHP/5.3.6
X-Nonspam: None
```

but from the code I use to send the email:

```
$headers = "From: notspam@foo.com\r\n".
           'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
           'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . "\r\n".
           'Return-Path: admin@foo.com';

$additional = "-radmin@foo.com";
$retMail = @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers, $additional); 
if (!$retMail)
{
    $error = htmlspecialchars($php_errormsg);
}
else
{
    $error = "";
}
```

I'm not putting that attribute on the header.

Additionally I just grep'ed the source for PHP 5.3.6 (which is what the host provider has me on) and that attribute does not appear in there as well.

I found a number of examples of "spamwatch" emails on the web with the attribute in the header, but I've found no documentation on it specifically (I know about "X-PHP-Originating-Script" - is this a precursor?).

Frankly, I think the hosting site is pointing at a red herring but I wanted to get some groupthink on it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yeah, that alone won't trip a spam filter.  That plus a few other things might.

Comment: don't expect development support from your host, its not there job

Comment: Any other things you might thing of? I'm not an email admin by trade, so I don't know enough to say "B.S." on them yet.

Comment: "just the emails didn't leave the email server." are you sure about that?

Comment: @Dagon - I don't expect development support - I expect them not to mess with my business because they are tweaking things that I can't see and then give me incorrect information as to the cause of the issue.

Comment: you will find you signed up to allow this. dont like it, get a VPS

Comment: @Dagon - I am - PHP did not return an error - the script had been working smoothly for 10 months - nothing changed - then silence.

Comment: theres a huge difference between mail not arriving in a users inbox and it didn't leave the server, did your host say it did not leave the server?

Comment: @Dagon - and yes - I understand that I am ultimately responsible for my code. It is just that their excuse stated does not make sense to me.

Comment: @Dagon - Yes, they did - they also made a change to their spam filtering files and the emails are now flowing. It is just that their excuse makes no sense.

Comment: Yes.... I just wanted to know about X-PHP-Originating-Id...

Comment: RE: VPS - Yeah... I have that much time to manage one of those...

Comment: i wish had your *problems* lol

Comment: send mail to your self, check the headers, is there a 'X-PHP-Originating-Id' ? i usually only get a "X-PHP-Originating-Script:"

Comment: Yes, it is there - has been there for 10 months now.

Comment: My guess is that the hosting provider has extended PHP to put it in for their own tracking - but then why blame the spam filter on it?

Comment: full mail headers please

Comment: Well, if you are not adding `X-PHP-Originating-Id` to the mail yourself, then it’s most likely the MTA doing this … as a measure to make investigating abuse easier. (What IP address does it actually contain – your own one, that you called the script with I presume.) But as Eli already said, if your hoster put it in there, then blaming it as the reason as well is kinda weird.

Comment: What is the `From:` address you are using, is `foo.com` actually the domain under which your script is running? Or you the “owner” of that email address (or in any other way “rightfully” sending emails on their behalf)? If so, you might want to ask your hoster to implement SPF.

Comment: The form is to email customer info from our website to the principals of the business (me and my partner) - foo.com is not our real site. The hoster implements SPF in TXT file format.

Comment: Edited for the full headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eli, I think your thoughts are correct.

`X-PHP-Originating-Id` is not added by PHP anywhere. It adds the `X-PHP-Originating-Script` header. ([Source 1](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.mail.add-x-header))

I don't think `X-PHP-Originating-Id` is a precursor, it is not anywhere in the commit history for PHP. `X-PHP-Originating-Script` was added in PHP 5.2, iirc.

It's not mentioned in the Exim config files, it's not known to spamassasain.

Even a search on http://opensearch.krugle.org/ found nothing. It must be something added by the hosting company, with a patch most likely sitting inside PHP.

What hosting company are you with?